# Comparing current and template IntelliJ projects

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to update my template project with the setting that I've built up in my current one. I create enough projects, mostly for branches that this will save me time. Does anyone who of some tools or techniques for doing so? Even some information on where the template project is stored would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default project is stored as `${idea.config.path}/options/project.default.xml`. [idea.config.path depends on your OS](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181).

I am not aware of any tools you can use except some visual diff tool, especially considering that it will become multiple files when stored in .idea directory format.